# Finding and replacing last segment of ip addresses with sed

Tags: json, regex, bash, sed

I have bunch of json files that contains web events. Each event contains lots of stuff and I'm trying to do ip address anonymization (replacing last segment of ip addresses with 0) with `sed`.

**In short:**

How to find substrings like `"ip":"34.542.3.34"` from json files and transform them to `"ip":"34.542.3.0"`?

**Attempts:**

1. Resetting starting point with `\K`

`sed -e 's/"ip":"[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.\K[0-9]{1,3}/0/g' file.json`

This would work but unfortunately `sed` doesn't seem support reseting starting point.

2. Negative lookbehind

`sed -e 's/(?<="ip":"[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.)([0-9]{3})/0/g' file.json`

This would also work but negative lookbehind doesn't seem to support non-fixed-width assortions. So `[0-9]{1,3}` is not supported and hence this won't work.

3. Matching groups

Third idea was to use matching groups and do something like this

`sed -e 's/("ip":"[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|([0-9]{1,3})/\1\20/g' file.json`

But couldn't figure out how this would actually work with `sed`.

4. Writing regex for every possible length option separately

This would probably work but it would make regex too long and hardly readable. I would like to find more convenient and clean solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do your json files have same format scructure(levels)? post one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there's no `-r`-option:

```
sed -e 's/\("ip":"[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\(\.[[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\)\{2\}\.\)\([[:digit:]]\{1,3\}\)"/\10"/g' tst.json
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/("ip":"[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)[0-9]{1,3}(")/\10\2/' file
```